# Combining 2 SQL SELECT queries Into one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have (2) tables (1) is `Prices` and the other is `Orders`

**Prices:**

```
Symbol varchar
Open decimal
High decimal
Low decimal
Date DateTime
```

**Orders:**

```
Ticker varchar
Enter decimal
EntDate datetime
Exit decimal
ExtDate datetime
```

I'd like a query that give me all the pricing data for a specific datetime range and all the orders for that symbol for that same datetime range:

```
SELECT
   T1.Symbol
   , P1.Open
   , P1.High
   , P1.Low
   , P1.Close
   , P1.Date
   , O1.EntDate
   , O1.Enter
   , O1.ExtDate
   , O1.Exit
FROM Prices AS P1 
INNER JOIN ORDERS AS O1 ON O1.Ticker = P1.Symbol
WHERE P1.Date < CONVERT(datetime, '01/01/2012 10:00 AM')
```

Obviously this just does not work, I get multiple listings for Orders repeated for every line of Price Data.

Example Prices Table

```
 Sym    Open   High    Low    Close    Date
 ABC     1         3         1           2        1/1/2011 10:01 AM
 ABC     1         3         1           2        1/1/2011 10:02 AM
 ABC     1         3         1           2        1/1/2011 10:03 AM
 ABC     1         3         1           2        1/1/2011 10:04 AM
 ABC     1         3         1           2        1/1/2011 10:05 AM
 ABC     1         3         1           2        1/1/2011 10:06 AM
 ABC     1         3         1           2        1/1/2011 10:07 AM
 ABC     1         3         1           2        1/1/2011 10:08 AM
 ABC     1         3         1           2        1/1/2011 10:09 AM
 ABC     1         3         1           2        1/1/2011 10:10 AM
```

Example Orders Table

```
Sym  Enter   EntDate            Exit ExtDate
ABC   1      1/1/2011 10:-00    3    1/1/2011 10:02 AM  
ABC   1      1/1/2011 10:-03    3    1/1/2011 10:04 AM
```

Example Output for Prices and Orders Query with Date and EntDate < 1/1/2011 10:07 AM  AND Symbol = ABC

```
Sym    Open   High    Low    Close               Date                Enter  EntDate                 Exit      ExtDate
ABC     1         3         1           2        1/1/2011 10:01 AM     1    1/1/2011 10:-00         3         1/1/2011 10:02 AM
ABC     1         3         1           2        1/1/2011 10:02 AM     1    1/1/2011 10:-03         3         1/1/2011 10:04 AM
ABC     1         3         1           2        1/1/2011 10:03 AM
ABC     1         3         1           2        1/1/2011 10:04 AM
ABC     1         3         1           2        1/1/2011 10:05 AM
ABC     1         3         1           2        1/1/2011 10:06 AM
ABC     1         3         1           2        1/1/2011 10:07 AM
```

Comment: Looks like you need to add an additional filter on `O1.EntDate` or `O1.ExtDate` to restrict that by range but not sure what you mean by "I get multiple listings for Orders repeated for every line of Price Data" and why that is a problem. It is expected with joins. Maybe provide some example data and desired results.

Comment: I will give you example output above...

Comment: I will give you example output above... I tried too much data to fill the window.. essentially the problem is that the Orders Data repeats itself, which provides duplicate data which is a problem.  Perhaps Joins will not work for having a table full of price data but only a few records / lines with Orders information.

Comment: You just need to provide a few rows of example data for each table sufficient to demonstrate the issue then tell us what you want the results should look like.

Comment: Example Data and output given, thanks..

Comment: Yes looks like you're trying to glue together 2 unrelated result sets. You cannot use a `JOIN` to return 7 rows for some columns and 2 for the rest. (It would be kind of possible to do this with nulls but not really something that SQL is intended for)

Answer (score 1):

you need to have P1.Symbol
and not T1.Symbol

Answer (score 0):

Consider joining only the orders for the same day as the `Price` row:

```
from    Prices as P1 
left join 
        Orders as O1 
on      O1.Ticker = P1.Symbol
        and p1.Date <= O1.ExtDate and O1.ExtDate < dateadd(day,1,p1.Date)
```

Comment: I am going to have to do two sql command and them merge them in my presentation layer, as I continue to populate each record / line of my sql table with multiple orders... this gives me repeating orders up to the Pricing Date = Orders EntDate